# error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode6, ios8.1

I am going to upgrade the xcode 4.3 to xcode 6 while running i got this issue.Please help me.

```
Ld Derived data/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QR\ codeTests.octest/QR\ codeTests normal i386
    cd "/Users/iMac7/Desktop/Receipt Scan by vinod "
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=5.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch i386 -bundle -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk -L/Users/iMac7/Desktop/Receipt\ Scan\ by\ vinod\ /ramesh/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Users/iMac7/Desktop/Receipt\ Scan\ by\ vinod\ /Derived data/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator8.2.sdk/Developer/Library/Frameworks -F/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Receipt\ Scan\ by\ vinod\ /Derived data/Build/Intermediates/Warranty\ Info.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QR\ codeTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/QR\ codeTests.LinkFileList -bundle_loader /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Receipt\ Scan\ by\ vinod\ /Derived data/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QR\ code.app/QR\ code -Xlinker -objc_abi_version -Xlinker 2 -fobjc-link-runtime -Xlinker -no_implicit_dylibs -mios-simulator-version-min=5.0 -framework UIKit -framework Foundation -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Receipt\ Scan\ by\ vinod\ /Derived data/Build/Intermediates/Warranty\ Info.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/QR\ codeTests.build/Objects-normal/i386/QR\ codeTests_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Receipt\ Scan\ by\ vinod\ //Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QR\ codeTests.octest/QR\ codeTests
```

Comment: There should be a more-detailed error message just before the "exit code 1" line if you expand the link command in the build log.

Comment: this is the info i got, ld: file not found: /Users/iMac7/Desktop/Receipt Scan by vinod /Derived data/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/QR code.app/QR code

Comment: @PhillipMills OCUnit (SenTestingKit) is deprecated, please convert to XCTest.i got waring message also

Comment: when i add to xctext to my project there is no framework like xctext.how can is solve,please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quit the xcode 6 and open in the xcode 5.i got the error 255.
after solve this i run in xcode 6,I got solution for that.